# CakePHP: onError method in AppModel is not called when there is a sql error

Tags: php, cakephp, error-handling

I have added the onError method to AppModel as follows:

```
class AppModel extends Model {
    function onError() {
        $db = $this->getDataSource();
        $err = $db->lastError();
        $this->log("AppModel.onError: $err");
    }
}
```

Inside my matches controller I have:

```
function admin_create() {
    $this->Match->query('SELECT bang FROM');
}
```

When I visit /admin/controllers/create it get the following error in the log file but nothing from the code in the onError method.

> 2011-11-24 20:50:43 Warning: Warning (512): **SQL Error:** 1064: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line
>   1 in
>   [/home/larry/workspace/cbhk/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php,
>   line 684]

Also, when I set a breakpoint in admin_create it is reached but the breakpoints in onError cannot be reached.  Any idea as ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe the onError callback is executed when using the Model's query() method - only an exception is thrown if there is a SQL error.

**EDIT:**

Sorry, I should have provided an example of how you could handle the error:

```
  try {
    $this->Match->query('SELECT bang FROM');
  } catch (Exception $e) {
  /**
   * Catch the exception - do your error handling here
   */
  }
```